# Java app's transparent JPanel is garbled when run on Kubuntu

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, java, plasma, transparency

I have a Java application that works perfectly fine on Windows and apparently on Mac as well, but I cannot get it to work on Kubuntu without overlapping, garbled output. I have tried launching the Java application with both the bundled OpenJDK as well as Oracle's Java 8.

Here's a picture:

[image: kubuntu java issue]

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.io.*;

public class spob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new spob();
    }

    private JLabel label;
    private String[] anArray = {
        "<html><font color=green>- spO2:91  pr:65</font></html>",
        "<html><font color=red>+ spO2:85  pr:77</font></html>",
        "<html><font color=green>- spO2:90  pr:68</font></html>",
        "<html><font color=orange>+ spO2:89  pr:76</font></html>",
        "<html><font color=orange>- spO2:89  pr:72</font></html>",
        "<html><font color=orange>+ spO2:88  pr:73</font></html>",
        "<html><font color=red>- spO2:87  pr:78</font></html>",
        "<html><font color=red>+ spO2:86  pr:73</font></html>",
        "<html><font color=green>- spO2:92  pr:74</font></html>",
        "<html><font color=green>+ spO2:90  pr:71</font></html>"
    };
    private Random randomno = new Random();

    public spob() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("spO2 pr");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                // Transparent window...
                frame.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                BackgroundPane pane = new BackgroundPane();
                // Set this to 0.0f to make it fully transparent
                pane.setAlpha(0.0f);
                //pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                //pane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
                frame.setContentPane(pane);

                label = new JLabel("-");
                label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 28));
                label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                frame.add(label);

                frame.pack();
                Dimension size = frame.getSize();
                size.width = 400;
                frame.setSize(size);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        label.setText(anArray[randomno.nextInt(9 - 1) + 1]);
                        label.getParent().repaint();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

        private float alpha;

        public BackgroundPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
            this.alpha = alpha;
            repaint();
        }

        public float getAlpha() {
            return alpha;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(getAlpha()));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

I found documentation on Oracle's site to test transparency supported on a given system, and I ran the tests on my Windows machine. All three tests return true, but on Kubuntu only the PerPixel ones return true, the uniform translucency returns false.

Here's a picture:

[image: kubuntu results]

Here's the code used:

```java
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.*;

public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

    boolean isUniform = gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(TRANSLUCENT);
    boolean isPerPixel = gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT);
    boolean isShaped = gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT);

    GraphicsConfiguration[] configurations = gd.getConfigurations();
    System.out.println("Default screen device: " + gd.getIDstring());
    for (int i = 0; i < configurations.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("  Configuration " + (i + 1));
      System.out.println("  " + configurations[i].getColorModel());
    }
    System.out.println("isWindowTranslucencySupported Uniform: " + isUniform);
    System.out.println("isWindowTranslucencySupported PerPixel: " + isPerPixel);
    System.out.println("isWindowTranslucencySupported Shaped: " + isShaped);
  }
}
```

Comment: qubanshi.cc/questions/3513628/java-window-translucency-on-li‌​nux that post says he needed to use a NON VM machine, with dedicated graphics card drivers. My kubuntu machine uses intel cpu for integrated graphics, its an intel i5-3570k, wondering if maybe the graphics driver is to blame, lspci | grep VGA shows: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: also in the above screenshot I am showing my kubuntu vbox, but the computer with the i5-3570k has kubuntu 16.04 installed natively, and it returns the same results.

Comment: guess i will see if i can round up a system with an nvidia card and try testing the code then.... but its very hard to believe that with how modern the intel graphics is in the i5, that it can't handle something as simple as translucency, i really think something must be up with the driver that kubuntu ships with for this to not be working. I will post back after testing with an nvidia card.